# Mathematica Exports EPS with Extra White Characters and Outline in BarLegend

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, color, eps-format

Observe the following Mathematica code.  Forgive me that it's so long:

```
test[y_] := 
 ArrayPlot[Table[nd[y, 1, K, n], {K, 1, 15}, {n, 1, 15}], 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  DataReversed -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black], 
  FrameTicks -> {Range[15], Range[15], Range[15], Range[15]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black], FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  LabelStyle -> Black, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend["DarkRainbow", LegendLayout -> "Row", 
     LegendLabel -> "P", 
     LabelStyle -> 
      Directive[11, Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
     Method -> {Frame -> False, 
       TicksStyle -> Directive[Black]}], {Below, {0.54, 1}}]]
Export["test.eps", test[5]]
```

I just can't figure out why it's doing this.  The file that ends up getting exported to .eps ends up having a bunch of extra white characters and an outline in the bar legend!  I put the EPS file on top of a blue background in Illustrator to point it out.  See the arrows in the image below:
[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  Is there anything that I can do in order to remove those extra white characters as well as that outline?  Thank you.